# \refstepcounter in minted env. increases counters by two

Tags: cross-referencing, counters, minted

I want to do numbering certain lines in minted and refer it through cross-reference.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand*{\lnumformat}[1]{$\quad\leftarrow$ <#1>}
\newcounter{lnum}
\newcommand{\lnum}[1]{\refstepcounter{lnum}\lnumformat{\arabic{lnum}}\label{#1}}
\newcommand{\lref}[1]{\lnumformat{\ref{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[breaklines=true,linenos=true,escapeinside=@@]{cpp}
int main() { 
    printf("hello, world"); @\lnum{line1}@
    return 0; @\lnum{line3}@
}
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

And, here's the result:

[image: result]

As you can see, the counter number increases by two not one.
How can I fix it to increase by one?

Comment: Just to help the next one who will try to help... The code works fine if we use it in lstlisting environment and the counter increases by one this way... Your problem has to do with minted package... but unfortunatelly I don;t think I can help

Comment: I also tryed to install mintec on debian 9 and it doesn't compile not even the documentations simpler examples... Sorry... but I can't help... Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code in `@...@` is executed twice, apparently because of `breaklines=true`.

You can make `\lnum` do the stepping only once by executing it in the second pass; in the first pass we only add a phantom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand*{\lnumformat}[1]{\mbox{$\quad\leftarrow$ <#1>}}
\newcounter{lnum}
\newcommand{\lnum}[1]{%
  \ifcsname used@#1\endcsname
    \refstepcounter{lnum}\lnumformat{\arabic{lnum}}\label{#1}%
  \else
    \leavevmode\phantom{\lnumformat{\the\numexpr\value{lnum}+1}}%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname used@#1\endcsname{}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\lref}[1]{\lnumformat{\ref{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[breaklines=true,linenos=true,escapeinside=@@]{cpp}
int main() { 
    printf("hello, world"); @\lnum{line1}@
    return 0; @\lnum{line3}@
}
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]